# Variable Scope and Functions

Tags: php

For years I have done something like this:

config.php

```
<?php

   $db = array("user" => "username", "pass" => "password");
```

functions.php

```
<?php
   require_once('config.php');
   function connectToDatabase() {
       $dbc = new PDO($dsn, $db['user'], $db['pass']);
       // Do some stuff ...
   }
```

I've just read the PHP manual and that SHOULDNT work, but for years it has. Are there any server configurations that allow that to work?

I've just coded a new script and getting errors. The $db array is not even initialized.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, there are **no** variables in scope at the beginning of your `connectToDatabase` function. You should have gotten warnings about undeclared variables, too. Maybe it worked because of the configuration of your database installation that caused it use default usernames and passwords?

Comment: If this is in fact the explanation I hereby officially declare this technique to be called *programming by serendipity*, or, as @Pekka should understand, *mehr Glück als Verstand*. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should in fact never work, not even in older PHP versions nor with `register_globals`.

To import a global variable into a function, you need a `global $varname;` statement, or pass the variable to the function (which is generally preferable, as [globals are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)). The only exception are superglobals.

Are you 1000% sure it was  not like this:

```
   function connectToDatabase() {
       require_once('config.php');
       $dbc = new PDO($dsn, $db['user'], $db['pass']);
       // Do some stuff ...
   }
```

?

Comment: I'm just checking through some of my scripts and they contain my original example. I have a dedicated centos server that was configured by myself a while back. It's what I host all clients jobs on. I know it seems strange, and even impossible, but it's what I've been doing up until today when it had me stumped for over an hour because it wasnt working.

Comment: @Jamie weird! Then what @deceze suggests is the only explanation I can think of.